# Getting user from Lambda called by API Gateway using Cognito credentials

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

Calling my API endpoint from the browser using Cognito credentials doesn't provide the lambda function with the user that made the request.

I'm using AWS_IAM auth for the endpoint

This is what the request looks like in my lambda:

`module.exports.addItem = (event, context, done) => {
   console.log(event.identity);
   /**
    accountId: "",
    apiKey: "",
    caller: "",
    cognitoAuthenticationProvider: "",
    cognitoAuthenticationType: "",
    cognitoIdentityId: "",
    cognitoIdentityPoolId: "",
    sourceIp: "213.229.49.108",
    user: "",
    userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_6....",
    userArn: ""
    */
};`

I want to perform some dynamodb operations for the user. How can I get the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options to get the Cognito Identity Id to your Lambda function:

1. Check "use caller credentials" on your API method in the console. This will tell API Gateway to use the Cognito credentials to call Lambda, meaning the context.identity of your Lambda function will contain the information. **NOTE** Your Cognito role will need permission to invoke your Lambda function for this to work.
2. Use a [mapping template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html) to map the value into your event payload.

It looks like you are trying to do #2, but you haven't included your mapping template, please make sure this includes the required values. Also, ensure you've deployed the change that enabled IAM auth and that you are correctly signing the request.